# Using Option with .map() and .getOrElse()

Tags: scala

I am trying to read a value from a `Map[String, String]` given a key.
This key|value is optional, in that it might not be there
So, I want to use Option and then `map` & `getOrElse` as below to write the value if it's there, or set it to some default in case it's not there.

```
val endpoint:String = Option(config.getString("endpoint"))
    .map(_.value())
    .getOrElse()
```

The code above fails with "Symbol value is inaccessible from this place"

config is a `Map[String, Object]`

`getString` is a method on config that takes in the key, and returns the value

```
public String getString(String key){
    <...returns value...>
}
```

I could just drop the Option() and do, but then I have to deal with the exception that will be throw by getString()

```
val endpoint:String = config.getString("endpoint")
```

Any ideas what's wrong with this, or how to fix this? 
Better ways of writing this?

UPDATE: I need to mention that config is an object in an imported Java library. Not sure if that makes a difference or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, `config.getString` will throw an exception when the key is not present. In this case, wrapping the call in `Option()` will not help catch that exception: you should wrap in `Try` instead and convert that to an `Option`.

`Try[String]` represents a computation that can either succeed and become a `Success(String)`, or fail and give you a `Failure(thrownException)`. If you're familiar with `Option`, this is very similar to the two possibilities of `Some` and `None`, except that `Failure` will wrap the exception so that you know what caused the problem. The `Try(someComputation)` method will just do something like this for you:

```
try {
    Success(someComputation)
} catch {
    case ex: Exception => Failure(ex)
}
```

The second thing to consider is what you actually want to happen when there is no value. One sensible idea would be to provide a default configuration, and this is what `getOrElse` is for: you can't use without giving it the default value!

Here is an example:

```
val endpoint = Try(config.getString("endpoint"))
    .toOption
    .getOrElse("your_default_value")
```

We can do even better: now that we're using `Try` to catch the exception, there is no need to convert to `Option` if we're going to access the value right away.

```
val endpoint = Try(config.getString("endpoint")).getOrElse("your_default_value")
```

Comment: When I try the first example, with the .toOptionMap(_.value) I get the same error as with my code - "value is inaccessible from this place". Somehow value isn't known. Weird.

However, if I try the 2nd way, this appears to work just fine.

Comment: When I hit . after _ inside of the map() the intellisense that pops up makes me think that I am dealing with a String because I see methods like charAt, chars …. things I expect to see on Strings. 


So, this is why value isn't found, cause there is no such thing as value on a String. 

But why?

Comment: I don't know where you got the `.map(_.value)` from actually. We need more information about `config`, what is its exact type?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a value from a map like this.

```
val m: Map[String, String] = Map("foo" -> "bar")
val res  = m.get("foo").getOrElse("N.A") 
val res2 = m.getOrElse("foo", "N.A") // same as above but cleaner
```

But perhaps if you want to use pattern matching:

```
val o: Option[String] = m.get("foo")
val res: String = o match { 
  case Some(value) => value
  case None => "N.A"
}
```

Finally, a safe way to handle reading from config.

```
val endpoint:String = config.getString("endpoint") // this can return null
val endpoint: Option[String] = Option(config.getString("endpoint")) // this will return None if endpoint is not found
```

I suspect the config object might even have a method like

```
val endpoint: Option[String] = config.getStringOpt("endpoint")
```

Then you can use pattern matching to extract the value in the option. Or one of the many combinators `map`, `flatMap`, `fold` etc

```
val endPoint = Option(config.getString("endpoint"))

def callEndPoint(endPoint: String): Future[Result] = ??? // calls endpoint

endPoint match { 
  case Some(ep) => callEndPoint(ep)
  case None     => Future.failed(new NoSuchElementException("End point not found"))
}
```

Or

```
 val foo = endPoint.map(callEndPoint).getOrElse(Future.failed(new NoSuchElement...))
```